# Delegating from Objective-c to c (Or maybe better calling it: Creating listener from C to OBJ-C)

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c, delegates

Everyone knows that we can create listener (delegation pattern) in an IOS project with delegation. We create a protocol and conform to the protocol in in the observe class and then implement the methods in the observer class.

This is working in both Obj-c, Swift and also if we have a C++ then form we can delegate the C++ in the obj-c. This is very cool because then anyone that want to get noticed can register to the callers and get notified.

My question is, Does anyone know how do we do that if we have C methods that we need to Observe in the obj-c class (There is no inheritance so we need to do it in another way)

I don't have code to show as i just dont understand how to start.
I was told that i need pointer to function to solve this but really got lost.

The scenario is:

> 1. There is an old Log file written in ***C*** that we discovered that is not doing all we need. This file can not be changed
> 2. There is a new ***Objective-c*** Logger class That is doing everything correctly but is in another project in the framework.
> 3. For backward compatibility and code coherence for developers that are using the SDK for a long time, It was decided that the C++ delegation approach is not good and what i need to do is that every time the **C** Log method is being called it need to alert (delegate) the **obj-c** Logger that will do what ever it suppose. (The **C** Logger will not call the method in the **obj-c**, it had to be with delegation or pointer to function in **C** case?)

C++ Code Snippets:

***ILogger.hpp and ILogger.cpp:***

```
#include "ILoggerObserver.hpp"

namespace dat
{
    class ILogger
    {
        std::vector<ILoggerObserver*> list;

    public:
        void Attach(ILoggerObserver *libNet);
        void Detach(ILoggerObserver *libNet);
        void LogNotifier(LOG_LEVEL::log_level_e logLevel, const std::string &message);
    };
}
#endif /* ILogger_hpp */

#include "ILogger.hpp"
#include <algorithm>

using namespace dat;

void ILogger::Attach(ILoggerObserver *libNet)
{
    list.push_back(libNet);
}
void ILogger::Detach(ILoggerObserver *libNet)
{
    list.erase(std::remove(list.begin(), list.end(), libNet), list.end());
}

void ILogger::LogNotifier(LOG_LEVEL::log_level_e logLevel, const 
std::string &message)
{
    for(std::vector<ILoggerObserver*>::const_iterator iter = list.begin(); iter != list.end(); ++iter)
    {
        if(*iter != 0)
        {
            (*iter)->LogNotifier(logLevel, message);
        }
    }
}
```

***ILoggerObserver.hpp (There is no .cpp file needed):***

```
namespace dat {
    class ILoggerObserver
    {
    public:
        virtual void LogNotifier(LOG_LEVEL::log_level_e logLevel, const std::string &message) = 0;
    };
}

#endif /* ILoggerObserver_hpp */
```

> And then:
>
> In the observe we just inherit from ILogger and call
>   ILogger::LogNotifier when ever we need.
>
> In the observer we inherit from ILoggerObserver and call Attach(this)
>   in the constructor and Implement LogNotifier (what ever we called it
>   in ILoggerObserver) and that is all!!!

I think that the solution for obj-c might be same as delegating C++ to C, so if anyone knows how to do it over there it might help also.

Any Ideas?
10x

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right
You can rebind C's functions with that library: https://github.com/facebook/fishhook
to your own.

Comment: 10x but is is not the solution... I an looking to create a (delegate like) listener from an action created in a .C file to an .M (OBJ-C) file... it is very simple in any OOP language and i've implemented it in lots of them but i can't do it in this scenario (Everyone is saying it is very simple also in C but no one is able to explain it beyond telling me it is pointer to function. But saying that something is pointer to function is like telling someone that is lost "turn right"! you know it is not the full instruction but that is what people know how to explain i guess.